# Грамматическая основа предложения. Сказуемое

Tags: грамматика

Помогите, пожалуйста, выделить грамматическую основу в предложениях:

1. На ней было длинное шелковое платье (было платье или платье было длинное шелковое?).
2. У девушки была длинная черная коса, смуглое лицо, узкий правильный нос.

Влияет ли порядок слов на грамматическую основу? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обоих предложениях  *быть* – не связка, а знаменательный глагол (= *иметься*).

1. ***На ней было длинное шелковое платье***.

***Платье*** – подлежащее;
***было*** – сказуемое.

2. ***У девушки была длинная черная коса, смуглое лицо, узкий правильный нос***.

***Коса, лицо, нос*** – однородные подлежащие;
***была*** – сказуемое, согласованное в роде с ближайшим к нему подлежащим ***коса***.

> Влияет ли порядок слов на грамматическую основу?

Влияет.

В предложении с изменённым порядком слов:

***(На ней) платье было длинное, шелковое***

– сказуемым (при подлежащем *платье*) будет уже характеристика платья: ***было длинное, шёлковое***.